# A* algorithm with google maps API

Tags: google-maps, a-star

I want to implement an A* Search Algorithm with google maps's API, but how can I get the coordinates just from the streets, not from the houses etc? And how can I get the neighbor's coordinates from this specific street coordinate? How can I identify crossroads? Does someone have an idea? I need this to trace a route, but I don't want to use google's algorithm
*Coordinates= Latitude,Longitude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The street data is not available via the Google Maps API for use in other routing algorithms read the [terms of service](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#tos)).  You will need to use an open source for mapping data like [Open Street Maps](http://www.openstreetmaps.org)

Comment: I saw the XAPI of the OSM, but I have some questions.
How can I pass the name's city and retrieve the coordinate of it? how check if this coordinate is in the bounds of the street? how catch the next coordinate or neighbors of that coordinate in the bounds of the street?

Comment: You need to ask that of someone that uses those APIs, maybe create a question tagged openstreetmap (or change the tag on this one and update your question).